# Programming ATMega328 from arduino with separated power supply

Tags: arduino, spi, opto-isolator

I actually need to update the code on a project who use an ATMega328. I'm using an arduino as a SPI programmer.

So, I need TX/RX and RESET pins to program the external ATMega328.

My problem is, the actual ATMega328 run on an other power supply than the programmer. Is it a problem ? Should I use optocouplers to connect the two circuit for the programming ?

I can replace the power supply by the +5V/GND of the arduino, but I'm just wondering as this could be really easier for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as both the device and the programmer share grounds and use the same signaling levels, the device can be programmed directly.

If they share grounds but do not use the same signaling levels then you will need to use a level converter.

If they do not share grounds then you will need to use optocouplers.

Answer (score 1):

You question regarding the electrical connection has been answered by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams but I'm in doubt about the connection scheme you intend to use.

> I actually need to update the code on a project who use an ATMega328. I'm using an arduino as a SPI programmer.
>   So, I need TX/RX and RESET pins to program the external ATMega328.

If by SPI you mean ISP then it doesn't involve the Tx/Rx pins but SCK/MISO/MOSI, like

[image]

On the other hand if you are trying to program an external mega328 that already has a bootloader (through that bootloader functionality) then you only need to use the USB-to-serial converter of the arduino board and connect the Tx/Rx lines. The connection will be like

[image]

source: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard

Comment: Ho yeah, sorry, I pick the wrong terms and my question wasn't clear, it's the second case.

Comment: @EmmanuelIstace Connecting just the ground will be enough (assuming 5v operation for both boards) but it shouldn't be much trouble to get the power from arduino. In either case both will work.